# Binding SQL Server objects explorer pane using SMO

Tags: wpf, xaml, smo

I'm trying to create SQL Server objects explorer pane in wpf using SMO

(`Microsoft.SqlServer.ConnectionInfo.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Sdk.Sfc.dll, Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo`)

like this:

- Server 50.80.90.90

  - DB1

    - Tables

      - tbl1
      - tbl2
      - tbl3
    - Procedures
    - Views
    - Functions
  - DB2
  - DB3

This is my attempt:

CS

```
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;

public partial class SQLPaneDemo : Window
{
        public SQLAssigner()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            //Connect to local sql server instance
            Server srv = new Server();
            treeView1.ItemsSource = new List<Server> { srv };
        }
}
```

Xaml

```
<Window x:Class="SQLPaneDemo.SQLPaneDemo"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:mdl="clr-namespace:Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo;assembly=Microsoft.SqlServer.Smo"
        Title="SQLPaneDemo" Height="300" Width="300">
    <DockPanel>
        <TreeView x:Name="treeView1"/>
    </DockPanel>
    <Window.Resources>
        <HierarchicalDataTemplate DataType = "{x:Type mdl:Server}" ItemsSource = "{Binding Databases}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </HierarchicalDataTemplate> 
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:Database}">
            <TreeViewItem x:Name="DBtvItem" Header="{Binding Name}">
                <TreeViewItem Header="Tables" ItemsSource="{Binding Tables}"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Procedures" ItemsSource="{Binding StoredProcedures}"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Views" ItemsSource="{Binding Views}"></TreeViewItem>
                <TreeViewItem Header="Triggers" ItemsSource="{Binding Triggers}"></TreeViewItem>
            </TreeViewItem>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:Table}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:StoredProcedure}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:Trigger}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
        <DataTemplate DataType="{x:Type mdl:View}">
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </Window.Resources>
</Window>
```

It throws an exception when binding db objects as it may has IsAccessable equal false, how can I bind element DBtvItem only when Database.IsAccessable == true? do you have any ideas/projects/controls about this topic?
And this is my demo https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBgbqcnNgX_Rk83QUU0T0R4Qnc/view?usp=sharing
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Not enough information. What was the type of Exception thrown. Is Database your own custom type?

Comment: @Glen Thomas
SqlException: Database 'ReportServerTempDB' cannot be opened. 
No this is not my own type and this is my demo project https://drive.google.com/file/d/0ByBgbqcnNgX_Rk83QUU0T0R4Qnc/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

Your login may not have access to that DB.  It is one of the two DBs created by default with the SSRS installation.